# Tried to rebuild dist folder but fail

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I found a great library, which can make draft.js even better.

https://github.com/jpuri/react-draft-wysiwyg

I create a project, and npm install this library.

But inside this library's folder, I tried to rebuild the dist folder, 
cause I customize some setting in my project.

When I run **npm run build**, it gave me some error:

```
ERROR in ./src/Editor/index.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (41:19)

  40 | export default class WysiwygEditor extends Component {
> 41 |   static propTypes = {
     |                    ^
```

I already create node_modules & config/webpack.config.js inside this library's folder.

why is that happen?

---

Added my **webpack.config.js** at following:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const precss = require('precss');

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'source-map',
    entry: [
        './src/index',
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, '../dist'),
        filename: 'react-draft-wysiwyg.js',
        library: 'reactDraftWysiwyg',
        libraryTarget: 'umd',
    },
    externals: {
        react: 'react',
        immutable: 'immutable',
        'react-dom': 'react-dom',
        'draft-js': 'draft-js',
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('production'),
            },
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            compressor: {
                warnings: false,
            },
        }),
        new ExtractTextPlugin('react-draft-wysiwyg.css'),
        new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
            options: {
                postcss: [autoprefixer, precss],
            },
        })
    ],
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: /immutable\.js$|draftjs-utils\.js$/ },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: 'style-loader',
                    use: 'css-loader?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[local]!postcss-loader',
                }),
            },
            { test: /\.(png|jpg)$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=8192' },
            {
                test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
                loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml',
            },
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.json'],
    },
};
```

Comment: Can you add your webpack.config.js?

Comment: @Michael thx for reply, I added at following, plz have a look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you don't transpile your code in a way that can recognize static class properties. If you are using babel, this can be enabled by using the Class Property Transform:
https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/

Comment: Hello, thanks for reply.
But I am not really familiar with webpack, could you tell me how to put "transform-class-properties" inside "plugins"?(I follow the tutorial you gaved, but fail)

Comment: It's not Webpack. It's Babel. Create file named .babelrc on your project's root directory. Then, follow the usage instructions here: https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/#usage-via-babelrc-recommended-

Comment: Thanks dude ! I create ".babelrc" file and follow the usage, then it works!